# sqlite 3 query - columns after case statement ignored

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I'm using SQLite 3 in a project. Everything has worked very well indeed until now. I wrote a query selecting several columns, followed by a case statement, followed by more columns. All columns after the case statement were ignored. For example:

```
  select column1, column2,
  case when condition then value1 else value2 end as column3,
  column4, column5
  from myTable
```

(The foregoing is not the actual query but represents its format.) column1, column2 and column3 appear in the result set but not column4 or column5. I tried several different queries, tried encapsulating the query as a view, etc. - always with the same effect. Am I doing something wrong, is there a bug in SQlite, or what?

Comment: If you have a problem with your SQL, you need to post it here. Posting something else that is *similar* won't help you (or us) find an answer. The mere invention of new similar code can hide or change the actual problem. Please [edit] and post your actual SQL statement here if you want us to help you troubleshoot it. From [help]: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. However, quite literally, I tried numerous queries conforming to the above pattern and they all exhibited the same behavior - so my intention in posting the pattern rather than specific SQL was to say that "anything like this gives me the same problem." And the case statement syntax is correct because, as I wrote, it itself returns a result. By executing queries from C# code, I discovered that the queries work fine. It appears that it is the SQLiteAdmin tool that exhibits the problem, not SQLite itself. Therefore, SQLiteAdmin users will do do well to be aware that this happens.

Comment: I also replaced the case statement(s) with coalesce function call(s), with the same results - works in C# code, not in SQLiteAdmin.

Comment: Try adding "AS some_name": select column1, column2,
  case when condition then value1 else value2 end as column3 AS SOME_NAME,
  column4, column5
  from myTable

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d1f61/1).

Comment: Your mistake must be somewhere else. Post your code!